# Vertica : in a MERGE, changing the UPDATE when a condition is met

Tags: sql, merge, insert, vertica

I proceed to an update of a table in my vertica database using the following method:

- upload my list of rows to update in a staging table  stg_table
- operate an insert in my new table :

  ```
  MERGE INTO table imb USING stg_table stg ON stg.member_id = imb.member_id
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET     next_segment = stg.next_segment,
  untildate = stg.untildate

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
  (member_id,
   previous_segment,
   current_segment,
   next_segment,
   untildate) 
  VALUES
  (stg.member_id,
   stg.previous_segment,
   stg.current_segment,
   stg.next_segment,
   stg.untildate)
  ```

Now I'm interested in putting another condition : I want the "UPDATE" to only occur if some condition is met both on table and stg_table.

Basically, I wanted something like :

```
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET     next_segment = stg.next_segment,
    untildate = stg.untildate
    WHERE stg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='y'
```

==> This doesn't work because I cannot put a WHERE here in Vertica

I also tried :

```
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET     next_segment = IF(stg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='x',stg.next_segment,imb.next_segment)
    untildate = IF(stg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='x',stg.untildate,imb.untildate)
```

==> This doesn't work because I seem to not be able to use an IF here

I also thought of putting my additional conditions in the "ON", but I'm afraid it will then go through "INSERT" when the member_id matches but not my additional conditions.

If anyone knows how I can do to do what I want to achieve, i.e.

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE "but sometimes do not actually update if some additional condition is met in these cases pls do nothing"

**What Works**

elirevach pointed me that CASE instead of IF will function :

```
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET     next_segment =  CASE stg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='x'  THEN stg.next_segment ELSE imb.next_segment END,
    untildate = CASE stg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='x' THEN stg.untildate ELSE imb.untildate END
```

Another way to proceed, but more heavy, would be to simply launch 3 requests :

```
   MERGE INTO table imb USING stg_table stg ON stg.member_id = imb.member_id  AND  MyOtherCondition
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...

   MERGE INTO table imb USING stg_table stg ON stg.member_id = imb.member_id  AND  NOT MyOtherCondition
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...
```

And the insert :

```
   MERGE INTO table imb USING stg_table stg ON stg.member_id = imb.member_id  
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...
```

Comment: Do you try instend of IF , CASE?

Comment: Somting like  (never test it  in real envrionemnt ) ,  
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET     next_segment =  case when tg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='y'  then stg.next_segment else next_segment  end ,
            untildate  =    case when tg.next_segment='x' AND  imb.current_segment='y'  then  stg.untildate elae untildate

Comment: your solution works yeah, I can accept it if you post it as an answer, even if it was more a basic syntax issue than true programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somting like (never test it in real envrionemnt ) , WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET next_segment = case when tg.next_segment='x' AND imb.current_segment='y' then stg.next_segment else next_segment end , untildate = case when tg.next_segment='x' AND imb.current_segment='y' then stg.untildate elae untildate –

Comment: Thanks it worked ! Added your solution (and the workaround I had done) in my question